# Interchanging Integration and Differentiation

Tags: integration, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to apply the following corollary of Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence theorem:

"Suppose the function $h(x,y)$ is continuous at $y_{0}$ for each $x$, and there exists a function $g(x)$ satisfying:

i. $|h(x,y)| \le g(x)$ for all x and y,

ii. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)dx < \infty$

Then,

$\lim_{y \rightarrow y_{0}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x,y)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{y \rightarrow y_{0}}h(x,y)dx$"

...to the below function's central moment generating function to find the 2nd, 3rd, & 4th central moments as follows:

$f(x) = e^{-x}$  $\quad$     $x \ge 0$

$C_{x}(t) = E(e^{t(x-\mu)}) = e^{-t\mu}E(e^{tx}) = e^{-t\mu}M_{x}(t)$

Where C and M represent the central mgf and the mgf, respectively.

My result was as follows:

2nd central moment = $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t\mu}.e^{tx}.e^{-x} dx \;\lvert_{t=0}$

applying the above corollary yields:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-t\mu}.e^{tx}) dx \;\lvert_{t=0}$

= $\frac{((t-1)x-1)e^{tx-x-t}}{(t-1)^2}\lvert_{0}^{\infty}$

at t=0, this evaluates to **0**

However, I know for a fact that the second central moment is **1**

Can someone help me figure out what's going wrong here? I'm guessing that the second requirement displayed above is not satisfied to be able to do the interchange.

Comment: Don't you have convergence problems for $t\geq 1$?

Comment: Yes, but since I only care about t in the neighborhood of $0$, then that should not be a cause for concern

Comment: yes, sure. Then you should be able to use exactly DCT to interchange limit and integral, take $|t|<\delta$ and use the mean value theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To justify the interchange of limit and integral, estimate the difference quotient  as follows: Let $|t|<\delta<1$,

$$
\left|\frac{e^{-t(\mu-x)}-1}{t}\right|e^{-x}\leq e^{-x}\sup_{|t|<\delta}|x-\mu|e^{-t(\mu-x)}\leq e^{-(x-\delta|x-\mu|)}|x-\mu|
$$
Which is integrable. Now apply the DCT to find 
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t(\mu-x)}-1}{t}e^{-x}\mathrm dx
=\int_0^\infty \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{-t(\mu-x)}-1}{t}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\\
=\int_0^\infty (x-\mu)e^{-x}\mathrm dx\\
=1-\mu
$$
Which computes the *first* central moment, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I went through my calculations again. You are absolutely correct, it does work. I was mistakenly taking only the first derivative (which yielded the first central moment) while comparing it to the second central moment (which requires the second derivative).

Comment: Great. I’m glad I could help!